# Trying to get Post Details Using REST API wordpress in flutter but some information is missing like phone and price

Tags: wordpress, flutter, wordpress-rest-api

Trying to get Post Details Using REST API WordPress in flutter but some information is missing like phone and price.

[Here's my json response of REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48tEW.png)

[Heres my Wordpress post and am not able to get these fields in json while using REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bm2P.png)

Comment: The information you are trying to fetch it the meta information of the post so you need to modify your API to get the meta info in the API. There is nothing wrong with the flutter.

Comment: @MuhammadAshir am not much familiar with API building, am using default REST API, Can You suggest to me any code to do this?
Thanks

Comment: You can look at the WordPress Rest API. Here you can check https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/